# заменить дублирующиеся байты

Tags: c++

Есть последовательность байтов, которая может содержать определенные пары байтов. Надо эти пары найти и заменить на одинарные.

пример входной последовательности:

```
{ 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x11, 0x7f, 0x7f };
```

ожидаемая выходная:

```
{ 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x11, 0x7f };
```

Решено так:

```
const unsigned char _ssp_stx = 0x7f;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void stx_shrink(std::vector<char>& data)
{
    std::vector<char> result;
    result.reserve(data.size());

    bool stx_lock { false };

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (stx_lock == true)
        {
            stx_lock = false;

            if ((unsigned char)data[i] == _ssp_stx)
                continue;
        }

        if ((unsigned char)data[i] == _ssp_stx)
            stx_lock = true;

        result.push_back(data[i]);
    }

    data = result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> test = { 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x11, 0x7f, 0x7f };

    stx_shrink(test);

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли решить с меньшей сложностью и избавиться от одного-двух ифов в цикле?

По итогу я пришел к такому варианту (версия @Qwertiy):

```
void stx_shrink(vector<char>& data)
{
    if (data.size() < 2) return;

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    for (; i < data.size() - 1; ++i, ++j)
    {
        if (i != j)
            data[j] = data[i];

        if (data[i] == _ssp_stx && data[i + 1] == _ssp_stx)
            ++i;
    }

    if (i == data.size() - 1)
        data[j++] = data[i];

    data.resize(j);
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь отредактировать вопрос, чтобы не возникало двузначности. Иначе кажется, будто вы хотите заменить все отрезки повторяющихся байт одним байтом.

Comment: @zcorvid, для исключения неоднозначности я добавил пример, но вы решили что там ошибка

Comment: Значение повторяющегося байта всегда известно? Или другие тоже могут повторяться и их надо объединять?

Comment: @mkkik всегда известно

Comment: Повторений для других байтов не может быть?

Comment: Вот, эти вопросы в комментариях и означают, что вопрос задан недостаточно чётко. Например "Значение повторяющегося байта всегда известно" из вопроса совершенно не следует.

Comment: `data = result;` - а так вообще разве можно делать?

Comment: Там по ссылке аргумент передаётся, всё путём. правда std::swap лучше бы зашёл

Comment: Да нормальный код. В конце лучше `data = std::move(result);` p.s `if (stx_lock == true)`  улыбнуло.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а почему нет?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко, да, ты прав, так можно. Я попутал ссылку с указателем и подумал про указатель на вектор из стека. PS: Я уже ответ написал с решением в один цикл.

Comment: @Qwertiy Оно тут у всех в один цикл. Так-то

Comment: @vegorov, я имел в виду без дополнительной памяти и флагов.

Comment: @Qwertiy `Я уже ответ написал с решением в один цикл.` Да??? В любом случае, ваше решение  должно работать быстрее. Только я так не понял как оно работает. Ну в смысле я уже 20 минут сижу в отладчике и рисую на бумаге схему, что куда там двигается

Comment: @vegorov, Если вам так важно не использовать доп память, то не создавайте `result` вообще, создайте `size_t new_index = 0`, вместо `result.push_back(data[i]);` делайте `data[new_index] = data[new_index];` `++new_index;`, а вместо `data = result;` - `data.resize(j);`. `i` у вас всегда >= `new_index` и ничего нужного не перезапишется.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко я вторую версия добавил в свой ответ

Comment: @mkkik, могут быть, но удалять необходимо только повторения определенного байта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал гораздо проще и без создания нового вектора (заодно поменял тип `_ssp_stx`, чтобы каждый раз не приводить, если требуется, можно вернуть приведение):

```
const char _ssp_stx = 0x7f;

void stx_shrink(vector<char> &a)
{
  if (a.size() < 2) return;

  unsigned i = -1U, q = -1U, n = a.size() - 1;

  while (++q < n)
    if ((a[++i] = a[q]) == _ssp_stx && a[q+1] == _ssp_stx)
      ++q;

  if (q == n)
    a[++i] = a[q];

  a.resize(i+1);
}
```

Код полностью (вместе с проверкой): https://ideone.com/Zv6Vjy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const char _ssp_stx = 0x7f;

void stx_shrink(vector<char> &a)
{
  if (a.size() < 2) return;

  unsigned i = -1U, q = -1U, n = a.size() - 1;

  while (++q < n)
    if ((a[++i] = a[q]) == _ssp_stx && a[q+1] == _ssp_stx)
      ++q;

  if (q == n)
    a[++i] = a[q];

  a.resize(i+1);
}

int main()
{
  vector<char> a = { 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x11, 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> b = { 0x7f, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x7f };
  vector<char> c = { 0x7f, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> d = { 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x7f };
  vector<char> e = { 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> f = { 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> g = { 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> h = { 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> i = { 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f };
  vector<char> j = { 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f };

  stx_shrink(a);   for (char x : a) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(b);   for (char x : b) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(c);   for (char x : c) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(d);   for (char x : d) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(e);   for (char x : e) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(f);   for (char x : f) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(g);   for (char x : g) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(h);   for (char x : h) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(i);   for (char x : i) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;
  stx_shrink(j);   for (char x : j) cout << hex << (unsigned)x << ' ';   cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: На олимпиадный код смахивает. И Сишные касты - на них компилятор должен предупреждения кидать (в выводе в main)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95023/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vegorov).

Comment: Может вообще тогда всю программу в одну строчку запихнуть? И привыкайте, что присваивание в if даст ошибку и ничего не с компилируется. `(a[++i] = a[q])` даст warning, а warning это ошибка.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко 1. Нет никакого предупреждения, если присваивание в скобках. 2. Для меня такая запись выражает идею, что я хочу работать с одним и тем же значением.

Comment: я тоже сторонник стиля 1 операция - одна строка, так проще дебажить) еще `-1U` в студии нелегально. спасибо)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, можно поменять на `~0U` - тогда предупреждения не будет, но на мой взгляд читаемость снижается.

Answer (score 2):

Конечные автоматы может быть?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

enum State{
    Start,
    State1,
    State2
};

enum Symbol{
    B,
    Other
};


const std::array<std::array<State, 2>, 3> Table = {{
    {State1, Start},
    {State2, Start},
    {State1, Start}
}};

const unsigned char ssp_ptx = 0x7f;

Symbol getSymbol(unsigned char c){
    if (c == ssp_ptx){
        return Symbol::B;
    }else{
        return Symbol::Other;
    }
}

static State curState = State::Start;

State nextState(unsigned char c){
    auto symbol = getSymbol(c);
    return Table[curState][symbol];
}

std::vector<char> stx_shrink(const std::vector<char>& data){
    std::vector<char> ret;
    ret.reserve(data.size());
    for (const auto& c: data){
        curState = nextState(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
        if (curState != State::State2){
            ret.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> test = { 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x11, 0x7f, 0x7f };
    auto result = stx_shrink(test);
    std::cout << std::hex;
    for (const auto& c: result){
         std::cout << "0x" << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Схема переходов]

Версия без лишнего вектора `result` и с возможность запуска в многопоточном режиме. По мотивам ответа `Qwertiy`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

enum State{
    Start,
    State1,
    State2
};

enum Symbol{
    B,
    Other
};


const std::array<std::array<State, 2>, 3> Table = {{
    {State1, Start},
    {State2, Start},
    {State1, Start}
}};

const unsigned char ssp_ptx = 0x7f;

Symbol getSymbol(unsigned char c){
    if (c == ssp_ptx){
        return Symbol::B;
    }else{
        return Symbol::Other;
    }
}


State nextState(const State curState, unsigned char c){
    auto symbol = getSymbol(c);
    return Table[curState][symbol];
}

void stx_shrink(std::vector<char>& data){
    State curState = State::Start;
    std::size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    for (const auto& c: data){
        curState = nextState(curState, static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
        if (curState != State::State2)
            data[i++] = data[j++];
        else
            ++j;
    }
    data.resize(i);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> test = { 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x10, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x11, 0x7f, 0x7f };
    stx_shrink(test);
    std::cout << std::hex;
    for (const auto& c: test){
         std::cout << "0x" << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если честно, мне код автора кажется читабельней)

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Ровно до тех пор пока не окажется, что таких пар байтов больше одной. Ну в смысле что нужно будет ещё и 0xff дубли убирать, и тому подобное

Comment: Чего-то кода много...

Comment: @vegorov, вот кода окажется, тогда и нужно будет такое писать. В поставленной задаче это перебор. Да и код автора адаптируется под большое количество байт в 3 строчки.

Comment: задача казалось мне такой тривиальной..

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот и мой вариант, использует тот же вектор, копирует блоками, а не побайтно:

```
template<typename T>
size_t shrink_range( const size_t     range   
                            T * const where
                    , const T * const begin
                    , const T * const end   )
{
    const auto shrinked_range = (range / 2) + (range % 2);
    const auto shrink_count   = range - shrinked_range;
    const auto count = static_cast<size_t>(end - begin) - shrink_count;
    std::memmove(where, begin, count * sizeof(T));
    return count;
}

void stx_shrink(std::vector<char> & sequence, const char value)
{
   auto begin = std::data(sequence);
   auto where = begin;
   const auto end = begin + std::size(sequence);
   size_t total = 0;
   size_t range = 0;
   for(auto i = begin; i < end; ++i)
   {
       if(value == *i)
       {
           ++range;
       }
       else
       {
           if(range > 1)
           {
               const auto count = shrink_range(range, where, begin, i);
               where += count;
               total += count;
               begin = i;
           }
           range = 0;
       }
   }
   const auto count = shrink_range(range, where, begin, end);
   total += count;
   sequence.resize(total);
}
```

Comment: `(range / 2) + (range % 2)` - это же `(range+1) / 2`. А `memmove` в плюсах стоит с осторожностью использовать - для `char` нормально, а для чего-нибудь с деструктором может печально кончиться.

Answer (score 1):

Ищем по паре одинаковых байт, и удаляем первый из них:

```
const unsigned char ch { 0x7 };
std::vector<char> v {0x6, 0x3, 0x7, 0x7, 0x21, 0x7, 0x2, 0x7, 0x7, 0x22, 0x7, 0x7};

auto it = std::begin(v);
for (;;) {
    it = std::search_n(it, std::end(v), 2, ch);
    if(it != std::end(v)) {
        it = v.erase(it);
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
//0x6 0x3 0x7 0x21 0x7 0x2 0x7 0x22 0x7 
for(auto ch : v)std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << (int)ch << " ";
```

Comment: Так себе. Из-за `it = v.erase(it);` получается квадратичная асимптотика вместо линейной.

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему?

Comment: @Cerbo, потому что `erase` удаляет элемент, т. е. сдвигает все находящиеся после него на 1 позицию (у нас же вектор). Т. е. для каждого удаления необоснованно двигается весь хвост, хотя реально достаточно сделать 1 проход.

Comment: @Qwertiy А вы про это, я думал про мою правку.